# There is a logic error in a simple counting algorithm in my java code

Tags: java, count

So there is a logic error inside my simple java counting words, first of in cmd, it's asking me to type the string twice, when it should show once

I run this in cmd, here is the output:

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents>java count
shapeshifting
shapeshifting
Number of Occurrence of s is 2 in string shapeshifting
s
2
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class count5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = input.nextLine();

        char key = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        countString(str, key);
    }

    public static void countString(String str, char key) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == key)
                count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Occurrence of "
                + key + " is " + count + " in string " + str);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }

        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

So here some thing that confuses me:

1. why is there 3 lines needed allow user to type an input. I thought the previous line already let me enter the input. What is `char key = input.nextLine().charAt(0);` needed for, and the previous line? Shouldn't there be only input entering line?
2. Why is there 2 for loops inside the code, don't they do same thing?

Comment: "Why is there 2 for loops inside the code", this is your code so why are you asking this?

Comment: 1. What is char key = input.nextLine().charAt(0); needed for : it is getting the first character of the input, thought change it to char key = str.charAt(0);         2. Why is there 2 for loops inside the code, don't they do same thing? .. the first loop is checking if there is match for the first letter form the string, and the second loop is printing the match found the same number of times.

Comment: @VinodSinghBist can you write a full answer and I will accept it?

Comment: @javalover please check below, and let me know if that works for you

Comment: @VinodSinghBist thank you! so one last thing, String str = input.nextLine(); is just to make the input into string and then display at the next line? Is there way to combine the two line into one? Scanner input and string str = input.nextLine():?

Comment: you can change Scanner input and string str = input.nextLine(): 
  to String str =new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); , this will work in your case. Though if you need to read more lines of input from user, it's better to initiate the Scanner class instance and call upon the same as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution which should ask for one time input and traverse the complete input string entered for the match

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class stringCompair {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.nextLine();
    for(int i=0 ; i < str.length();i++) {
        char key = str.charAt(i);
        countString(str, key);
    }

}

public static void countString(String str, char key) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == key)
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of Occurrence of "
            + key + " is " + count + " in string " + str);
}
}
```